# What are the relevant sources behind what is required for a halachic conversion?

Tags: halacha, conversion-to-judaism

There is some variety of opinion on what is required for a conversion to be halachically valid ([example of such dispute](http://forward.com/opinion/11985/slamming-the-door-on-converts-00757/)) - rather than take an opinion based on who I *feel* should be counted as a valid convert, I'd like to read up on the relevant sources on the topic. What are the most relevant Talmud and other passages which inform thinking on this topic?

Answer (score 2):

I advise you to begin by reading the Tur and Bet Yosef [Yore Dea 268-269](https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A)  . In Bet Yosef you would  find most references to Talmud and further you can learn deeper in the Talmud itself and extend the study to Rishonim.  In a third time learning Rambam following the annotations  En Mishpat.  on Talmud,  and to re-read Tur Bet Yosef and Shulchan Aruch with Beur Hagara and Shach.   If you have a couple of precise questions perhaps I can help you more.